# Display Next/Prev Link to Post in same Category under specific Post Type on singular page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make next/prev links in my single post page, that'll link to the next post in the same Category in the custom post type.

`cpt_exhibit` <- custom post type

This is what I've got so far:

```
if ( is_singular( 'cpt_exhibit' ) ) :

    $terms = get_the_terms( $postid, 'ctax_exhibit_category' );
    $t_name = $terms[0]->slug;

    previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous in category', true, $t_name );
endif;
```

This is my vardump of `$terms`

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
    object(WP_Term)#2321 (10) {
      ["term_id"]=> 
        int(12)
      ["name"]=> 
        string(9) "Tank Park"
      ["slug"]=>
        string(9) "tank-park"
      ["term_group"]=>
        int(0)
      ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
        int(12)
      ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(21) "ctax_exhibit_category"
      ["description"]=>
        string(0) ""
      ["parent"]=>
        int(0)
      ["count"]=>
        int(15)
      ["filter"]=>
        string(3) "raw"
    }
}
```

Now $t_name spits out a slug, which matches the category made within `cpt_exhibit`, however I feel like I'm missing something. This doesn't output anything. I've tried changing `ctax_exhibit_category` to the custom post type, but then I get an error invalid taxonomy.

I didn't build out the custom post types, I am just making updates a client requested.

If anyone could help me, that'd be fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`previous_post_link` doesn't require a slug. You're passing the slug into the function where it's expecting excluded_terms.

Believe it should look something like:

`previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous in category', true, '', ctax_exhibit_category );`

The docs also [cover this briefly](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link#Post_Title_As_Link.2C_Within_Same_Custom_Taxonomy).

Comment: You sir, are awesome. Thank you so much for helping me with this! EDIT: The one thing I noticed, is that within a post with a category in that taxonomy, say `tank-park`, it will only cycle 2 or 3 posts then call it an end, despite that category having 10+ posts. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems the issue is resolved, it was due to the way the posts were imported, all without proper timestamps causing them to display as posted at the same time